# How can I update already exising @font-face delaration?

Tags: css, font-face, cascade

I have a case where I have already defined font-face declarations

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'some font';
  src: url('somelink') format('woff');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I have no ablilty to edit this code, but I need to add one more declaration(font-display: optional), is there a way to do that?

Currently what am I doing is that I am just overwriting this declaration in the stylesheet where I have control with something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'some font';
  src: url('somelink') format('woff');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: optional;
}
```

But I am not even sure if it works. How would you test that? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override `@font-face` definitions.

Common practice is to create a new `@font-face` with a different name and then use the new name in `font-family`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'some font 2';
  src: url('somelink') format('woff');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: optional;
}

.item {
  font-family: 'some font 2`
}
```